# Comparison of 2 different approaches to create class that imitates dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Is there any advantage that Code A/B gives over the other?
I am going to needs lots of such classes to define entities so that

1. I can access individual fields like I am accessing class attributes
2. instead of a plain json, I can determine type of its sub-fields at certain levels and then run some methods based on the same
3. A given entity may be a composition of multiple entities of same or different type

Code A:

```
class AProfile(object):
    """ composed of list of list of information heads
    """
    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'info', {"name": None,
                                         "pid": None,
                                         "interests": []
                                         "score": 0})
    def __getitem__(self, attribute):
        return self.info[attribute]
    def __setitem__(self, attribute, value):
        self.info[attribute] = value
    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return self.info[attribute]
    def __setattr__(self, attribute, value):
        if attribute.startswith('_'):
            super(AProfile, self).__setattr__(attribute, value)
        else:
            self.info[attribute] = value
```

Code B:

```
class BProfile(dict):
    """
    """
    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return self[attribute]
    def __setattr__(self, attribute, value):
        self[attribute] = value
```

Comment: The second approach will test `True` for `isinstance(value, dict)`, that's about it for differences, really.

Comment: You'll need to implement a lot more than the methods of `AProfile` if you really want to get that approach right. You can't use `in` yet, or iterate over such an object, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second approach has a major advantage.

In the first case:
You have to reinvent the wheel. And it's likely that you end up using a dictionary in your implementation. You have to implement the various methods that are already there in the dictionary like the comparison methods, operator methods etc.

Whereas in the second case:
It's building on the existing `dict` object. No need to reinvent the wheel, just adding some bells and whistles to it.

> Note: `collections.OrderedDict` is implemented using the 2nd approach.

Comment: already told by martjin and user2357112 but still marking your answer as correct so that the post is useful to others